# Why is EVP_DigestSignUpdate missing from my OpenSSL build?

Tags: visual-c++, openssl, erlang

I built OpenSSL 1.1.1g, but the `EVP_DigestSignUpdate` function is missing. And I can't figure out why.

This is on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 BuildTools. I followed the basic steps.

```
> perl .\Configure VC-WIN64A
> nmake
> nmake test
```

It builds with no errors, and all the tests pass (except skipped tests, see below).

But when linking with libcrypto.lib I get an error:

`mac.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestSignUpdate referenced in function mac_update`

There are a few other functions that fail to link as well, but this one is strange because the other `EVP_DigestSign*` functions are available (EVP_DigestSignInit, EVP_DigestSignFinal, EVP_DigestSign). 
I ran `dumpbin` and can see that they are all exported except `EVP_DigestSignUpdate`!

This is driving me crazy. Any ideas?

For reference, these are the skipped tests:

```
02-test_errstr.t ............. skipped: This is unsupported on MSYS/MinGW or MSWin32
05-test_md2.t ................ skipped: md2 is not supported by this OpenSSL build
05-test_rc5.t ................ skipped: rc5 is not supported by this OpenSSL build
30-test_afalg.t .............. skipped: test_afalg not supported for this build
40-test_rehash.t ............. skipped: test_rehash is not available on this platform
60-test_x509_store.t ......... skipped: test_rehash is not available on this platform
70-test_wpacket.t ............ skipped: Test disabled in this configuration
80-test_pkcs12.t ............. skipped: Non-Greek system locale
90-test_gost.t ............... skipped: No test GOST engine found
90-test_overhead.t ........... skipped: Only supported in no-shared builds
95-test_external_boringssl.t . skipped: No external tests in this configuration
95-test_external_krb5.t ...... skipped: No external tests in this configuration
95-test_external_pyca.t ...... skipped: No external tests in this configuration
```

In case anyone is curious, I'm trying to build Erlang/otp on Windows, and I'm almost there... These are the other linker errors in case it sparks a reminder of a similar problem:

```
cipher.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_CIPHER_mode referenced in function cipher_info_nif
mac.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestSignUpdate referenced in function mac_update
pkey.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding referenced in function pkey_sign_nif
pkey.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_pss_saltlen referenced in function pkey_sign_nif
pkey.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_mgf1_md referenced in function pkey_sign_nif
pkey.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_oaep_md referenced in function pkey_crypt_nif
pkey.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_set0_rsa_oaep_label referenced in function pkey_crypt_nif
pkey.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md referenced in function pkey_sign_nif
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little, I found that `EVP_DigestSignUpdate` is just a macro for `EVP_DigestUpdate`.

I built a sample program that links to OpenSSL and used EVP_DigestSignUpdate, and it worked just fine. There is nothing wrong with my OpenSSL build.

There must be a problem in the Erlang code somewhere, probably related to the horrible cc.sh wrapper for the VC++ compiler that has to run in bash scripts under cygwin/mingw/MSYS. I will ask a new question about building Erlang in Windows.